# Missing shared library : Sony small apps Error

Tags: android, sony

Hello i try to develop sony small apps i install all the thing in my eclipse follows all the step as i sony small app developer site.also  i have latest sdk version first i get problem is that i dont get in android virtual device as sony in target device popupthen i try with another target device. i chooce sample program and run it at that time i got erro missing shared library and got unavailable library ""  my menefest file is as follows please anyody give me a quick solution.

```
enter code here

      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             package="com.example.sonydemo"
             android:versionCode="1"
             android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="10"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.permission.SMALLAPP" />

     <application
              android:name="com.example.sonydemo.MainActivity"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <uses-library android:name="com.sony.smallapp.framework" />
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
     <service android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </service>
   </application>
 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find my own questions ans.

I solve the problem of target device as sony after doing following step : window -> sdk manager -> packages -> extra folder ->main step is now i Re-install the Sony device profiles.

now solution of visibility of avd :it is Seems like some bug from Google side, this problem found after "ADT 22.6" update.

so run avd from window->sdk manager->tools or from your sdk folder located and run avd managr.exe it solve: if you get error of any 'install the armeabi-v7a system image for android 4.1.2(api-16)' then also have solution of just download system image armeabi-v7a and simply replace with your system image , after doing this my application run very well.

Comment: Nice one Nirav :) Great job